# PyTorch doesn't import after installing Anaconda

Tags: macos, python-3.x, ipython, anaconda, pytorch

I just installed PyTorch after installing Anaconda, and when I run iPython using Anaconda Python, it won't find PyTorch.
[image]

[image]

However I can verify PyTorch is in the pkgs directory of my anaconda folder.
What's going on?

Comment: shouldn't you "import torch"?

Comment: come on don't paste images...

Answer (score 2):

While the framework name is Pytorch, it must be imported using the *torch* namespace like so `import torch`. If you look at the official documentation [here](http://pytorch.org/docs/), you will see any pytorch related module import like nn or autograd is done through the *torch* namespace. I admit it is a bit confusing but I guess it was done to instill a sense of familiarity for old torch7 users. Also, there is a very good introduction tutorial which you could probably use to familiarize yourself better with the ins and outs of pytorch found [here](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/deep_learning_60min_blitz.html). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The Py Torch package might have installed to a different python environment that you might have on your system.

You can see the entire list of python packages installed in your current environment using

`pip freeze`

Ensure that the `pip` command being executed belongs to Anaconda distribution. The following command will provide the path of the pip executable.

```
which pip
```